# Can a view be used to protect a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance which has a linked server connection to a central data store.  Our security team would prefer that the account used by our web pages not have direct access to that linked server, but we need to pull two columns of data out of that linked server connection.  Security is OK with those two pieces of data, but doesn't want the rest to be available to the web.

My question is this: Can a view be created which is able to get and return those two pieces of data which can be executed by an account lacking permissions to the source linked server?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: RBarryYoung's answer below lead me down another path, where I discovered Execute As ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx ).  This will allow me to create an "interface" stored procedure executable by the web page account which can in turn run the stored proc I want to run as an account with permission to the linked server.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: `Execute As` is the standard way to add temporary access-rights to a user/session. Be forewarned however, it may not work with Linked Severs becuase they go off-node/off-server. SQL Server may restrict Linked Server access to the session's 'Original_Login' value (sorry, I've done it before, but I cannot remember the specifics for Linked Servers).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I will update if I'm able to test this theory out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AFAIK, the only security enabling that can happen through a View is Owner-Chaining and that will not work through a Linked-Server.

I believe that you *can* do this with a Stored Procedure though because it has more security options than Views do.

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't by definition, A view can be defined to allow read/write access to a subset of data to which users are otherwise denied access.

Comment: @Sonam No, by definition a View is an encapsulation of a query expression.  Security features, if any are implementation-specific and added by the vendors.  In SQL Server, the only security access that can be enabled by a View is owner-chaining.  There's no other mechanism/syntax to specify enhanced access through a View that I know of.  If you know a way to specify it, then let us know.

Comment: Seems like you're correct in this not being possible, but your comment about doing this with a stored procedure led me down another path which I'll add in an edit to my question above.  Thanks!